# My ui-view did not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular JS and I'm got stuck when using ui-view.
I don't know ui-view or something else is trouble. But my navbar didn't appear.
Any help must be great!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <div ui-view="navbar"></div>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view="content"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
        .config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'navbar@': {
                    templateUrl: 'navbar.html',
                    controller: 'NavbarController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

navbar.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Help, please!

Comment: your `app` state is abstract, but doesn't have any descendants, so it wouldn't ever be accessed.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states

Answer (score 0):

As [Claies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/claies) pointed out you need to have descendants states, so that only your parent **abstract** state would be activated. Please check the answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hwhpm8Lz/2/)

In the run config you have to initialize/activate the root url by calling `$state.go('your.state.name')` or you have to use ng-route's `otherwise` api to activate the initial state. Here I have used unnamed view for content in `index.html`